# Difference between rpc and servlet techniques

Tags: java, http, networking, rpc

I would like to know what is the difference between rpc and servlet techniques?
Which one should one use in which case? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance. 
Horace

Comment: Your question is too general. Most RPC techniques are in fact based on servlets.

Comment: Thank you Marko. The answer to my question can be derived fromn the explanation here: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideServerSide

Answer (score 0):

- A servlet is used to extend the capabilities of servers that host applications accessed via a request-response programming model. Although servlets can respond to any type of request, they are commonly used to extend the applications hosted by Web servers. For such applications, use servelets.
- RPC is an structured programming semantics approach to call remote procedures. Use it when you want to call any remote method which is written in structured language like C.